# Edit Media query breakpoints

Tags: css, sass, bootswatch

I have been trying to edit the Media query breakpoints in Bootswatch (cyborg). I have edited the code below in the file _variables.scss and in variables.less (same sizing as _variables.scss) but nothing has changed. Do I need to edit anything else?

EDIT ** the IDE I'm using is Coda2 for Mac ****************

_variables.scss

```
//== Media queries breakpoints
//
//## Define the breakpoints at which your layout will change, adapting to different screen sizes.

// Extra small screen / phone
//** Deprecated `$screen-xs` as of v3.0.1
$screen-xs:                  580px !default; // changed from 480px 11.9.17
//** Deprecated `$screen-xs-min` as of v3.2.0
$screen-xs-min:              $screen-xs !default;
//** Deprecated `$screen-phone` as of v3.0.1
$screen-phone:               $screen-xs-min !default;

// Small screen / tablet
//** Deprecated `$screen-sm` as of v3.0.1
$screen-sm:                  950px !default; // changed from 768px 11.9.17
$screen-sm-min:              $screen-sm !default;
//** Deprecated `$screen-tablet` as of v3.0.1
$screen-tablet:              $screen-sm-min !default;

// Medium screen / desktop
//** Deprecated `$screen-md` as of v3.0.1
$screen-md:                  1000px !default; // changed from 992px 11.9.17
$screen-md-min:              $screen-md !default;
//** Deprecated `$screen-desktop` as of v3.0.1
$screen-desktop:             $screen-md-min !default;

// Large screen / wide desktop
//** Deprecated `$screen-lg` as of v3.0.1
$screen-lg:                  1200px !default; 
$screen-lg-min:              $screen-lg !default;
//** Deprecated `$screen-lg-desktop` as of v3.0.1
$screen-lg-desktop:          $screen-lg-min !default;

// So media queries don't overlap when required, provide a maximum
$screen-xs-max:              ($screen-sm-min - 1) !default;
$screen-sm-max:              ($screen-md-min - 1) !default;
$screen-md-max:              ($screen-lg-min - 1) !default;
```

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but did you compile your scss and less files to real CSS?

Comment: @PhantomLord No, not sure how that is done. Do you have a tutorial ?